# Using MAX() in VARCHAR Field

Tags: string, oracle, sorting

I have a table with following set of data

```
ID (VARCHAR2 field)
D001
D002
D010
D0012
```

I use `max()` in this field.

```
Select max(ID) from <table-name>;
```

It returns `D010` as result.

Why is the result not `D0012`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: It's a `varchar` field, why would it be sorted as a number?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You get `D010` because alphabetically, `D010` comes after `D0012` or said another way, `D01` comes after `D00` and therefore anything that is `D01x` comes after anything that starts `D00x`.

Comment: And here is an example, how to deal with such problem -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/16496963/1469208

Answer (score 5):

below code is working for me as per your expectation

```
select max(to_number(regexp_substr(id, '\d+'))) id from <yourtable>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `<TABLE_NAME>` 
ORDER BY CAST(  `ID` AS DECIMAL( 10, 3 ) ) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
Select MAX(ID) from table where IsNumeric(ID) = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work.

```
    select MAX(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(ID, 'D', ''), '', '') as int)) from <table-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Varchar need to Casted as int to select as MAX. Use below query:

`select max(CAST(ID as signed)) as max_id from <table-name>;`