# how to select max of mixed string/int column?

Tags: mysql, select, max, mixed

Lets say that I have a table which contains a column for invoice number, the data type is VARCHAR with mixed string/int values like:

```
invoice_number
**************
    HKL1
    HKL2
    HKL3
    .....
    HKL12
    HKL13
    HKL14
    HKL15
```

I tried to select max of it, but it returns with "HKL9", not the highest value "HKL15".

```
SELECT MAX( invoice_number )
FROM `invoice_header`
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`HKL9` (string) is greater than `HKL15`, because they are compared as strings. One way to deal with your problem is to define a column function that returns only the numeric part of the invoice number.

If all your invoice numbers start with `HKL`, then you can use:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(invoice_number, 4, length(invoice_number)-3) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM table
```

It takes the invoice_number excluding the 3 first characters, converts to int, and selects max from it.

Comment: Thank @nakosspy, but how I can do that using php/mysql?

Comment: The statement is standard SQL. You can execute it as any other statement.

Comment: I got it, it's: SELECT max(substring(invoice_number, 4, length(invoice_number)-3)) FROM table

Comment: SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(invoice_number, 4, length(invoice_number)-3) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM `table`

Answer (score 7):

```
select ifnull(max(CONVERT(invoice_number, SIGNED INTEGER)), 0)
from invoice_header 
where invoice_number REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer here because it works even if the invoice numbers have varying formats and it works without modifying the database.

Comment: This doesn't extract numeric part of invoice_number in case there are leading letters

Answer (score 5):

After a while of searching I found the easiest solution to this.

```
select MAX(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(invoice_number , 'HKL', ''), '', '') as int)) from invoice_header
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work also

```
SELECT invoice_number
FROM invoice_header
ORDER BY LENGTH( invoice_number) DESC,invoice_number DESC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is more one of definition & design.

**Select the invoice number with highest ID or DATE,** or  -- if those *really* don't correlate with "highest invoice number" -- define an additional column, which does correlate with invoice-number and is simple enough for the poor database to understand.

```
select INVOICE_NUMBER 
from INVOICE_HEADER
order by ID desc limit 1;
```

It's not that the database isn't smart enough.. it's that you're asking it the wrong question.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas W, but how I should ask for it, if I am asking the wrong way?

Comment: I think also it's order by desc.

Comment: The highest-numbered Invoice should be the most-recent;  by ID, or by Date. You should't expect databases to decode arbitrary strings, but they're really fast at doing primary-key index scans :)

Answer (score 1):

Below query can be used:

`select max(cast((CASE WHEN max_no NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN max_no END) as int)) AS max_int_no  from table1`

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For mysql database i use below :

```
SELECT CONCAT('HK','L',MAX(ABS(SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoice_number,'L', -1))))AS maxInvoice FROM invoice_header
```

because all invoice number can be use  letter "L" for an delimiter, use -> SUBSTRING_INDEX() function to split invoice number ,then use concat() function to concatenate them again for get the max invoice number.